# return entire line when search string is found

Tags: regex, string, perl, printing, line

I want to return the whole line when I find the search string in the line.

I'm getting most of what I need when I print but I'm short about 10 characters.  I get the start of the line and the string and about 10 characters after that but nothing more.

Here's my code (thanks in advance):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $calls_dir = "Ask/";
opendir(my $search_dir, $calls_dir) or die "$!\n";
my @files = grep /\.txt$/i, readdir $search_dir;
closedir $search_dir;
print "Got ", scalar @files, " files\n";

#my %seen = ();
foreach my $file (@files) {
    my %seen = ();
    my $current_file = $calls_dir . $file;
    open my $FILE, '<', $current_file or die "$file: $!\n";


    while (<$FILE>) {
        chomp;
        if (/^*(.*)Contact\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
            $seen{$1} = 1;

            foreach my $addr ( sort keys %seen ) {

                print "\n";
                print $file;
                print "\n";
                print "[$addr]\n";
                print "\n";
                print "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    close $FILE;
}
```

Comment: post some input and some output

Comment: If you're referring to `/^*(.*)Contact\s*(.*)\r?$/i` as the pattern you're matching, `$_` will contain the entire line - i.e. do a `print "$_\n";` after the if statement

Comment: How about the next line after that?  And the one after that?  I know I'm lame but I'm very new to perl so I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_ contains the entire line you're looking for