# VBScript Return an entire line when searching for a string

Tags: regex, string, vbscript, return, line

I want to return a whole line when I find the search string in the line. Similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464291/return-entire-line-when-search-string-is-found)

I know I can use this method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149698/read-txt-file-line-by-line-vbscript)

I wanted to know if there was an alternate way other other than doing a Regex on each individual line. I like FINDSTR, search for a term and it returns the whole line. Now I could also output that to a text file and read the text file instead, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you can multiline with RegEx in VBScript you could get the hole line in Group 1 with

```
^(.*(your Pattern).*)$
```

In your Pattern you put in yours and in Group 1 you get the whole line.